# Class Diagram generation from java code using ArgoUML not showing associations

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, argouml

I am using ArgoUML to generate automatically Class diagrams from Java code.

For that purpose, on ArgoUML, I`m doing: File -> Import Sources -> (I select the java files)

The problem is that if I have an association, the link between classes that I would expect in the Class Diagram doesn`t appear.

A Java code example that should show (in AgroUML) an association between the Flyable interface and the HotPursuit Class, but it does not show after auto class diagram generation:

```
public class HotPursuit {
  Flyable[] chasers;
  int _size;

  public HotPursuit(int size) {
     chasers =  new Flyable[size];
     this._size = size;
  }

  public void chase() {
    for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
      chasers[i].fly();
    }
  }
}
```

```
public interface Flyable {
  public abstract void fly();
}
```

Any way to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: It probably has more to do with Argo than Java.  You might want to reach out to them to see if it's a bug in their tools.

Comment: I'd say: Argo is dead. It was more a zombie than alive when I fiddled with it 20 years ago. A bug report I sent was worked on 5 years (or was it 7?) later. You might want to look for alternative UML modeling tools.

Comment: @qwerty_so I did not find a free UML modeling tool, which auto generates Class Diagrams from Java code. However, Argo still accomplishes its job!!!

Comment: But obviously not in all cases ;-)